# WPF: width column in graph

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts

I am writing because I have a problem with wpf and its graphics.
Basically, I want to create a column chart. My problem is that I can not set the width of the columns. On the internet I have only seen examples of columns with fixed width.

My XAML code is this:

```
<Grid Height="871" Width="572">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="337" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="65,0,0,496" Name="columnChart" Title="Column Series Demo" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="440">
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Wireless Power" Orientation="Y" Interval="100" />
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Time" Orientation="X" Interval="100" />
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Name="myGraph" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AnimationSequence="FirstTo"/>             
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

The code behind is:

```
private void showColumnChart(){

    List<KeyValuePair <int, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(12, 55));
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(15, 60));
    columnChart.DataContext = valueList;
}
```

Now, my purpose is to represent the strength of my wireless during the day. But there may be times when you are not connected, then power is nothing, or there are times when, for example, from 7.00 pm to 8.00pm the signal strength is equal to-78db. I have previously collected in a database and now I want to represent them. So my goal is, considering, for example, a time interval of 24 h, place the bars on the graph, where the x-axis is the detection time of the power of wireless, while the y-axis is the power.

I hope I have explained it well.

Comment: Why you can not set the width of the columns? Which columns you are talking about?

Comment: I'm using WPF ToolKit and i don't find the proprierty about the width. there's any?

Comment: I think that you should to investigate this question by yourself more carefully.

Comment: Believe me, I've done that. That's why I asked you.

Comment: So, be more specific in your question. Write the things you have tried, write the problem you have got and community will help to you

Answer (score 0):

In fact , to share with you my experiment of Wpf-toolkit / charting : i wish i had never installed this on my disk.
It would have been faster to go with :

1. a Canvas. (or even a good old grid).
2. one or several DataTemplates for the objects.
3. a controler object that handles the scaling (if need be).
4. and then an ItemControl within your Canvas, bound to an ObservableCollection.

After all, a bar chart is little more than a collection of styled rectangles...

My advice : Avoid Wpf toolkit, it is not documented. Impossible to get a clear idea, for instance, on how to handle colors as you want. Some tutorials/answers on forums simply cannot apply when you inspect the objects : the specifications changed many times.
So either the presets of the charts suits you, and go for it, but if you want to design freely your component, you'll be better off by yourself or by picking a documented/working lib.

If you go for another lib, i can't help you more : Google is your friend,
and if you want to do it by yourself, i did this quickly to get you started :

[image: snapshot of the bar-graph example]

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Datata}">
            <Rectangle Width="10"
                       Height="{Binding SomeValue}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Margin="10,0"
                       Fill="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--  Vertical Axis  -->
        <Path Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2">
            <Path.Data>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <!--  Horizontal axis  -->
        <Path Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2">
            <Path.Data>
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="0,5" >
           </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   ItemsSource="{Binding AllValues}"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I appreciate your work :-) But, do you know any other lib? i ask you because i have to do this graph through code and i think that to do this work in xaml-way is difficult for me.

Comment: if you appreciate, upvote it. If your not fluent in Xaml, pick a lib. As i said, i went for wpf toolkit, so i have no experience with another toolkit, so just go google / search "the code project"  / or stackoverflow to find advice or download libs.